# Squid3 don't caching, always TCP_MISS/200

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I have installed Squid3 and now I wont set it to caching WMTS's.
This is valid WMTS service url `http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/ORTO` and here is link to image from this service

```
http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/ORTO?service=WMTS&Layer=ORTOFOTOMAPA&style=default&Style=default&TileMatrixSet=EPSG:2180&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image/png&TileMatrix=EPSG:2180:0&TileCol=0&TileRow=0
```

And this is my config (output from squid3 -k parse)

```
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: http_port 8888
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 80
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: acl CONNECT method CONNECT
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: acl LAN src 192.168.1.0/24
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: acl connrate maxconn 200
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: http_access allow manager localhost
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: http_access allow localhost
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: http_access allow LAN
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: http_access deny connrate
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: http_access deny all
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: icp_access allow LAN
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: icp_access deny all
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: cache_mem 1024 MB
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: maximum_object_size_in_memory 1024 KB
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: cache_replacement_policy heap GDSF
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: maximum_object_size 4 MB
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: cache_swap_low 85
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: cache_swap_high 90
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: memory_pools on
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: offline_mode on
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: visible_hostname server.lan
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: minimum_object_size 20 KB
2015/03/30 14:20:29| Processing: cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3 4096 16 256
```

And lines in access.log always look like

```
1427716690.428    101 192.168.1.25 TCP_MISS/200 45157 GET http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/ORTO? - HIER_DIRECT/91.223.135.44 image/jpeg
```

Can anyone help me set it up?

Comment: What makes you think the miss isn't legitimate?

Comment: I don know do I understand question but there are always same images, so I want to cache them, so there need to show up TCP_HIT, I think.